# sql query on mongodb to get counts of multiple columns against the id value of single column

Tags: sql, mongodb

I am new to mongodb. I am stuck in a problem.

I want to get the counts of multiple columns against a single column's value containing an ID .

Suppose that I have different columns (`author1`,`author2`,`author3`,...so on) for a specific `id`.

Now I want to get the count of total authors for that specific `id` .

Therefore i want to count the total number of columns of authors against that ID to get the count.

Is this a good approach?

Comment: why don't you create a single column for author? so when you query for particular ID you'll get result with all authors associated and you'll get the count easily.

Comment: Actually i had a database of 8 million records and i have exported the json files in the database. the authors are the child table's columns of a parent table. therefore it seems difficult to make one column of all authors. do you have any easy approach for it?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an aggregated query with conditional sum, like :

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE
        WHEN (author1 = 'id' OR author2 = 'id' OR author3 = 'id' --more columns...)  
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0
    END
)
FROM table
```

Bottom line, you would be better off using a single column to store authors, so you could query just that column instead of looking at several of them.

Comment: CASE is not supported by mongodb sql